# Use powershell to delete Sharepoint online list item

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I currently have a powershell script to loop through a list on an Sharepoint online site.

```
$creds = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials("[USERNAME]", (ConvertTo-SecureString "[PASSWORD]" -AsPlainText -Force))  
$ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext("https://[SITENAME].sharepoint.com/sites/Projekter")  
$ctx.credentials = $creds  

try{  
    $lists = $ctx.web.Lists


    $list = $lists.GetByTitle("Ekstern synkronisering")
    $listItems = $list.GetItems([Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CamlQuery]::CreateAllItemsQuery())  
    $ctx.load($listItems)  

    $ctx.executeQuery()  

    foreach($listItem in $listItems)  
    {          
        $internal = $listItem["ConnectionString1"]
        $external = $listItem["ConnectionString2"]
        $folder = $listItem["Mappe"]
        $project = $listItem["Project"]
        $caseNo = $listItem["Title"]

        $doc = New-Object System.Xml.XmlDocument
        $doc.Load("C:\Script\PS-Layer2\xmlTemplate.xml")
        $ns = New-Object System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager($doc.NameTable)
        $ns.AddNamespace("ns", $doc.DocumentElement.NamespaceURI)

        $doc.SelectSingleNode("//ns:dataEntity[@name='Intern site']", $ns).connectionString = $internal+";Authentication=Office365;User Id=$userId;Password=$pwd;"

        $doc.SelectSingleNode("//ns:dataEntity[@name='Externt site']", $ns).connectionString = $external+";Authentication=Office365;User Id=$userId;Password=$pwd;"

        $doc.Save("C:\Temp\$caseNo - $project - $folder.xml")

    }  
}  
catch{  
    write-host "$($_.Exception.Message)" -foregroundcolor red  
}
```

This works fine to get the items and modify an XML file..

What I would like to do is, when the XML file has been created, it shall delete the listitem from the sharepoint site, so that it will not be created on the next run again.

Does anyone have a solution on that?

Best regards...

Comment: Consider using [PnpPowershell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/sharepoint/sharepoint-pnp/sharepoint-pnp-cmdlets?view=sharepoint-ps#lists) - There are several cmdlets dealing with adding, removing and updating ListItems - e.g. [Remove ListItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/remove-pnplistitem?view=sharepoint-ps)

Comment: Thanks that was the module I was looking fore :)